# Adding java library into MATLAB using javaaddpath

Tags: java, matlab, classpath

Consider the following commands:

```
javaaddpath('weka-latest.jar');
import weka.core.FastVector
```

When I run this the above code in Windows (MATLAB R2014a) it works perfectly fine. But in linux(MATLAB7.12.0 or R2011a) I get the following error:

```
??? Error using ==> import
Import argument 'weka.core.FastVector' cannot be found or cannot be imported.
```

Any idea how to debug this issue?

PS. The jar file is in this link: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/k4io5sh27rqns7q/weka-latest.jar?dl=0

Comment: On linux where did you put the file, is the directory you put the jar file in the MATLAB classpath ?

Comment: I gave the global path (full path). Would that make any difference?

Comment: Using the full path to the jar file should help

Comment: As I mentioned that's what I did

Answer (score 0):

It was MATLAB version problem. After installing MATLAB 2014b on my linux machine everything worked out fine.